# Create multiple tasks based on people picker field (allow multiple) using Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a Sharepoint list with a custom column of type People and Group (allow multiple).Now whenever I enter multiple values in this field, then on the Item added event we need to create individual tasks(create new item with assigned to field populated) for each of these users.

[image]

Would like to know how do i extract the individual email address/user ids in the workflow and assign them the tasks.

[image]

Whenever i log the above to history list, it get the values in the log correctly.

The issue is that whenever I use a single person, its assigned correctly but if I enter multiple users then it assigns only to the first user

I am using the SPD 2013 and the environment is Office 365(SharePoint online). I can do it via javascript (more dev efforts) or via Remote event receivers(more expensive) but would like to try it via Workflow. If its not possible I would also like to know if I can try it via Flow ?

Have checked this link - [SPD workflow to parse string](http://ssearcy-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2013/10/sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-parse_29.html) but didnt understand much

Comment: Did you find any solution in the end?

Comment: @Danilo - we ended up spending lot of time and effort on this, but we came to the conclusion that Event receivers were the best way. We also had another set of complications in the form of SP groups and Ad groups inside SP groups etc . So, we dumped workflows and used Remote event receivers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Task Assignment to Parallel while you assigning tasks through workflow. By default it will be set to Serial(create a task for 1st person and workflow instance will wait till that user completes that task)

When we change it to parallel workflow will create tasks for each users by parallel and wait for their approvals.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But i am looking for a method to extract email address from people field and then create a separate list item with `assigned to` field set to individual users.